# mvc trying to import excel files

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Exception error: An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

i'm trying to import excel files but it is not working, keep having exception at the specific area.

The given path's format is not supported FOR
Request.Files["in_FileUpload"].SaveAs(fileLocation);

```
public class ImportExcelController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /ImportExcel/
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFile in_FileUpload)
    {
        string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TutorNTuteeAppNew"].ConnectionString;
                                           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        if (Request.Files["in_FileUpload"].ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string fileExtension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(Request.Files["in_FileUpload"].FileName);

            if (fileExtension == ".xls" || fileExtension == ".xlsx")
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Content/")))
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/Content/"));
                }
                string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/Content/") + Request.Files["in_FileUpload"].FileName;

                if (System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
                {

                    System.IO.File.Delete(fileLocation);
                }
                Request.Files["in_FileUpload"].SaveAs(fileLocation); //ERROR HERE
                string excelConnectionString = string.Empty;
                excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                //connection String for xls file format.
                if (fileExtension == ".xls")
                {
                    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                //connection String for xlsx file format.
                else if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                {
                    excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=2\"";
                }
                //Create Connection to Excel work book and add oledb namespace
                OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
                excelConnection.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

Comment: Did you try attaching your debugger? What part of the line gives the exception? Is the result of Server.MapPath("~/Content/") as you expect? Is the contents of Request.Files["in_FileUpload"] as you expect?

Comment: People will be more likely to help you if you remove all the stuff that is clearly irrelevant, like the commented out code blocks, the GET action and pretty much anything after the exception.

Comment: yes, error at 'Request.Files["in_FileUpload"].SaveAs(fileLocation);'

Comment: Does `fileLocation` contain what you expect? Does `Request.Files["in_FileUpload"]`?

Comment: my file location under content has the file in_FileUpLoad

Comment: possible i give u my file and u edit for me, im really new into this field and my supervisor does not cares for me

Comment: Under the 'Content' Folder there is the in_FileUpload excel sheet